# How to unit test webapi controller sends back error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have the following controller method:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetAttractions([FromUri] SearchAttractionRequest request)
{
        try
        {
            var requestParameterType = request.RequestType();

            var searchResultModel = _attractionService.GetAttractions(request);

            return TransformListToResult(searchResultModel.Results, request.PerPage, searchResultModel.TotalItemCount, searchResultModel.GeneratedQuery);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          //  return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Any object");
          //  return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message));
        }
}
```

When making the call request.RequestType() if the parameter passed in is invalid an argument exception will be thrown and code will end up in catch block.  I have a unit test that I am trying to write:

```
[Test]
public void Given_Mixed_Parameters_Expect_Error()
{
        var invalidQuery = new SearchAttractionRequest
        {
            Category = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "|a catgeory|" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            Genre = "",
            Region = ""
        };

        var attractionServiceMock = Mock.Of<IAttractionService>();

        var sut = new AttractionsApiController(attractionServiceMock);

        Action act = () => sut.GetAttractions(invalidQuery);

        act.ShouldThrow<HttpResponseException>();
}
```

Basically I want to test that when I send in invalid param I get back error response.  So what do i need to send back from my api method and what do i need todo in my test to test for the error.  At the moment I am getting error in my test becuase the expected error is argument exception, which is correct but i want to mimic what a client would get back.

Do I need todo something like this in my test:

```
as OkNegotiatedContentResult<SomeObject>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't exactly write a test for the controller that will mimic what the client receives. That's because, by design, the controller is just a class with methods that return some result. Technically it doesn't determine what the client receives.

For example, if you call a method that throws an unhandled `ArgumentException`, other middleware is going to determine that the client should receive a 500 response. The controller isn't doing that.

Or, a controller might return a `ViewResult`. The client doesn't get a `ViewResult` - it gets HTML. The controller doesn't determine what that HTML will be.

When you're writing unit tests for the controller, think of it as just another class. You're just testing that it returns what it's supposed to.

If the controller throws an unhandled `ArgumentException` you can test for that. 
If you handle the `ArgumentException` and return

```
Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Any object");`
```

You could do this:

```
var result = (NegotiatedContentResult<string>)controller.GetResult();
Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, result.StatusCode);
```

Comment: Scott, exellent got it working, so i had update my controller method to return               return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message); and in my test i have             var result = (NegotiatedContentResult<string>)sut.GetAttractions(invalidQuery);

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could use the following:

```
var attractionServiceMock = Mock.Of<IAttractionService>();

var sut = new AttractionsApiController(attractionServiceMock);

var result = sut.GetAttractions(invalidQuery) as BadRequestErrorMessageResult;
Assert.IsNotNull(result);
```